# optimización select2 jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5, select2

hola tengo un campo select2 funcionando a la hora de conectar con base de datos pero tengo los siguientes inconvenientes: cuando limito x dato en el where en el momento de utilizar la búsqueda dentro del select2 ignora la restricción que se coloca, y el segundo inconveniente es que si por ejemplo cargo cantidades grandes de información el select2 se demora bastante en cargar faltaria la paginacion por ajax..

este es mi código:

```
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <title>Autocomplete con Ajax y Select2</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div style="width:520px;margin:0px auto;margin-top:30px;height:500px;">
  <h2>Autocomplete con Ajax y Select2</h2>
  <font class="">
    Select2 viene con soporte AJAX incorporada, usando métodos AJAX de jQuery. </font>
    <font>En este ejemplo, podemos buscar dentro de una tabla votantes.
  </font>
  <select class="categoryName form-control" style="width:500px" name="categoryName"></select>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $('.categoryName').select2({
        placeholder: 'Selecciona una categoría',
        ajax: {
          url: 'conexion.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          delay: 250,
          processResults: function (data) {
            return {
              results: data

            };
          },
          cache: true
        }
      });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

este seria conexion.php

```
<?php
define ('DB_USER', "root");
define ('DB_PASSWORD', "andra=22");
define ('DB_DATABASE', "dato1");
define ('DB_HOST', "localhost");
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM votantes WHERE nombres LIKE '%".$_GET['q']."%' ";  
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$json = [];
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
     $json[] = ['id'=>$row['id'], 'text'=>$row['nombres']];
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Intenta agregar esto: `data: function (q) {
            return {
                q: q
            };
        },`

Comment: si por ejemplo el where  tuviera fuera unicamente $_SESSION['edad']; me muestra correctamente la información pero si utilizo el  buscador del select2  me filtra pero de forma general y no me toma el where.

Comment: Ya intentaste agregar la opcion `data` al `select2`?  Tambien puedes probar con `term` en lugar de `q`.

Comment: cambie la consulta en el where nombres ='juan' y en el buscador me carga todos los registros que se llamen juan pero al utilizar el buscador asi este el registro o no este en la base e datos me carga todos los registros que se llamen juan, también implemente el data pero no hace nada..

Comment: listo ya lo puede lograr para el sistema de busqueda, implemente el  WHERE nombres LIKE '%".$_GET['q']."%'  AND nombres='juan' ";  pero ahora necesito que me haga paginación  el select2 ya que si cargo una base de datos grande se va a demorar mas de lo normal en cargar...